# How to find Root Path Name

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I want to use the `GetDiskFreeSpace()` function but I need the rootpathname. Given any filename input what function could I use to find its volume path name ?

My function to get input from the command line:

```
    string targetFile;
    cin.sync();
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Enter target file " << endl;

    getline(cin, targetFile);

    //if statement error handler for targetFile
    fstream file(targetFile.c_str());
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
    }
    file.close();
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Call `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`: *This parameter does not have to specify the root directory on a disk. The function accepts any directory on a disk.*

Comment: Well I'm trying to find out the cluster size(in bytes) of any file's volume usingGetDiskFreeSpace

Comment: @dspaces1 OK, I see that `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` doesn't yield that information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`PathStripToRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773757.aspx) function to do this.

Note that the documentation advises you to use the safer [`PathCchStripToRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707096.aspx) to avoid potential buffer overruns, but that is only available on Windows 8.

In order to support relative paths use `PathIsRelative` to detect a relative path. If the path is relative, pass the working directory to one of the functions above.

Comment: This works but what if the user is in directory already let's say inside C:\Users\Public\Documents and runs a script via cmd that targets a file called test.txt . Is there anyway to take the test.txt file and find out that it is on disk C:\

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand that question.  Just feed the full path to the function. If your filename is relative you need to specify what it is relative to. You can test if it is relative and if so feed the working directory to one of the functions in my answer. Use `PathIsRelative` for that.

Comment: Well if there isn't function that can take a file and find it's volume then I guess that's my only choice.

Comment: What do you mean by "take a file"?

Comment: So I'm trying to write a script that can be run from the cmd. If the user is already inside a directory that contains a file he wants to find out cluster information about he can just input text.txt and my script will do the rest.

Comment: So call PathIsRelative like I said.

Comment: The `PathStripToRoot` function only does string manipulation. If you have a volume mounted at `c:\MyVolume`, for file `c:\MyVolume\file.txt` it will return `c:` rather than correct `c:\MyVolume`.
The `GetVolumePathName` function returns a correct result in his case.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetVolumePathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. Bring relevant info from links into your answer in case links are later changed.